# Yahoo! Mail Notification in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, email, notifications, yahoo-mail

I have installed the following:

> sudo apt-get install mail-notification
>   sudo apt-get install mail-notification-evolution
>   sudo apt-get install fetchyahoo
>   sudo apt-get install getlive

and configured my yahoo email by setting my username to my_yahoo_id (and I tried my_yahoo_id@yahoo.com(
but i keep getting "my_yahoo_id@yahoo.com: unknown fetchyahoo failure"

Comment: Incidentally, you can also use `sudo apt-get install mail-notification-evolution fetchyahoo getlive`. `apt-get install` takes multiple arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It's described here: [E-Mail Notification in Ubuntu](http://dontsurfinthenude.blogspot.com/2009/11/email-notification-in-ubuntu.html), if you still need this. The FetchYahoo needs to be manually upgraded, because Synaptic Package Manager doesn't offer the last version.